# how do start cron in nextjs after server restart , we not using custom server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, backend, web-deployment

how do start cron in the next js after server restart?
**NOTE: we not using a custom server**.

we are using the next API routes.

how do trigger the function after the npm run start command. or else npm run dev.

Answer (score 1):

in your `package.json` you can create your custom "dev" function or modify which scripts will be run. Example:

```
"scripts": {
    "web:dev": "env-cmd -f environments/.env.development node server.js",
    "build": "next build ",
    "sitemap": "next-sitemap --config next-sitemap.config.js",
    "start": "next start"
  },
```

So, you can add the name of your file (need to create your nodejs file with functions needed) an it will be triggered